# Javascript - Involves Clicking images and making them disappear (very beginner)

Tags: javascript

I deeply apologize if I'm asking incorrectly or my question is just too simple for this site, but I don't have any more resources or any friends that can help me..

I have a couple of tasks in my class that I need to figure out how to do, using javascript on our website:

- We're given images of each letter of the alphabet and are designing a game in which we choose 5 images out of 7 images that are not visible yet.

1) The images dealt are random, but it is required that "G" is always one of the 7 images dealt

2) Once you pick 5 images, you cannot choose any more images, and when the fifth is picked, the other 2 images left will be flipped and then "disappear"

**I understand that the way it's worded, it seems like I'm asking for you to write all the code out for the entire program, but I just would like if someone could show me what code may have these tasks functional.  I'm at a deadend.**

*EDIT: I once again apologize, but it's really not necessary to vote down my post, I really have no where else to turn for the help and much of my grade is riding on it.*

Comment: I doubt you would be given these tasks without first learning something, can you show us the code you have so far?

Comment: I'm having a really hard time thinking up of ways to solve these prompts.  That's all our professor has given us, he told us our final will have the code, but this is what it's going to be tested on...I'm sorry..

Comment: I'm sure there are many ways to accomplish this, and the approach that you should use is likely what your professor is teaching in your course. Think about each step individually and how you would accomplish it first. For example, it sounds like you'll want an array of 6 random values, add an additional value for "G" to the array, display the array's corresponding images randomly on the screen with two images "flipped", add click events to each to "flip" them, include a counter so that you cannot flip more than 5, when the counter reaches 5 flip the remaining two cards, hide them.

Comment: Thank you (literally anything helps), I'll start looking at it that way - problem with my professor is that he doesn't teach very well and tells us to use w3schools for reference on stuff we haven't covered..which is a fair amount.

Comment: @user3614181 Sorry to hear that you do not have the right guidance (or so you think). I would encourage you to spend time on learning Javascript using some of the freely available online courses. Try [this free js course available on code academy](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript)

Comment: [W3Schools sucks](http://www.w3fools.com/) - no seriously I don't like that suggestion. The first part (generating the tiles) is pretty simple; however it has some options - are multiple of each allowed? Only Upper Case English alphabet or ?. Clear up those and that part is actually easy to answer. for the second part as @Goos said really. I'd suggest clearing up those questions, and if you can't figure out the array generation use a static array and try to do the rest and then edit the question with your code as best as you can do.

Comment: @bits unfortunately the final is tomorrow

Comment: @NickWilde only one of each letter is allowed, essentially each capital letter is on a card which are dealt

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
var chars = 'abcdefhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
var tiles = ['g'], num = 6;
while (num-- > 0) {
    tiles.push(chars[Math.rand() * chars.length]);
}
```

I suppose you can work out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

My method would be:

```
var x = ['A', 'B','C','D','E','F','G','H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M','N','O','P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];
var result = ['G']
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  result.push(x[Math.floor((Math.random() * 26))]);           
}
```

Then just work with result array; or alternatively something like this might work for you (ie if my assumptions on your environment are correct):

```
var x = ['A', 'B','C','D','E','F','G','H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M','N','O','P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];
result = '<img class="letter" src="images/G.jpg" alt="Letter G"/>';
for (var i = 0, l = ''; i < 6; i++) {
  l = x[Math.floor((Math.random() * 26))];
  result += '<img class="letter" src="images/'+l+'.jpg" alt="Letter '+l+'"/>';     
}
```

Comment: You can access the characters in a `string` like an `array`, so why not do that - e.g. `x = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'`? It's a lot shorter and easier.